# Python - access global list in function

Tags: python

I am new to Python, Before this, I was using C.

```
def cmplist(list): #Actually this function calls from another function
    if (len(list) > len(globlist)):
        globlist = list[:] #copy all element of list to globlist

# main
globlist = [1, 2, 3]
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
cmplist(lst)
print globlist
```

When I execute this code it shows following error

```
    if (len(list) > len(globlist)):
NameError: global name 'globlist' is not defined
```

I want to access and modify globlist from a function without passing it as an argument. In this case output should be

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Can anyone help me to find the solution?

Any suggestion and correction are always welcome.
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
Thanks Martijn Pieters for suggestion.
Origional error is

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'globlist' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Are you **sure** that that is the code that throws that exception? Because as written, you'd get `UnboundLocalError` instead.

Comment: In other words, you *can't* get a `NameError`, the name is clearly defined in the sample code you posted. More over, the code you posted assigns to the name `globlist` *in the function*, making it a local unless specifically overridden with a `global` statement as described in the answers below. But that only makes sense if you get a different exception for the code you posted.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience. Yes, it shows following error ` UnboundLocalError: local variable 'globlist' referenced before assignment`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
def cmplist(list): #Actually this function calls from another function
    global globlist
    if (len(list) > len(globlist)):
        globlist = list[:] #copy all element of list to globlist
```

It could be more Pythonic to pass it in and modify it that way though.

Comment: Or use `globlist[:] = list` and drop the `global` keyword. However, the exception given indicates a very different problem. The posted code and exception don't match up.

Comment: Thanks, Simeon, It works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare it as global in the function:

```
def cmplist(list): #Actually this function calls from another function
    global globlist
    if len(list) > len(globlist):
        globlist = list[:] #copy all element of list to globlist

# main
globlist = [1, 2, 3]
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
cmplist(lst)
print globlist
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside function cmplist, object 'globlist' is not considered to be from global scope. Python interpreter treats it as a local variable; the definition for which is not found in function cmplist. Hence the error. 
Inside the function declare globlist to be 'global' before its first use.
Something like this would work:

```
def cmplist(list):
     global globlist
     ... # Further references to globlist
```

HTH,
Swanand